# Why i am getting '406 Not acceptable' response from api when try to do post request with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

So i am trying to make a proyy server for a api. so my express server is getting some data and i have to make a post request to a external api with formdata payload.

I have tried with postman to hit the api and it works fine. The issue is when i am trying from my express server i am getting 406.

even i have copied the postman code same to same to my code that didn't worked as well.

This is my controller function:

```
add: async (req, res) => {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("trid", "");
        data.append("order_no", "");
        data.append("customer_name", "Ashutosh");
        data.append("customer_email", "ashutosh@gmail.com");
        data.append("customer_mobile", "");
        data.append("app_id", "2");
        data.append("id", "");
        data.append("cid", "");
        data.append("token", "");
        data.append("category", "Administrative");
        data.append("sub_category", "General Ticket");
        data.append("other", "");
        data.append("priority", "High");
        data.append("description", "this is description");
        data.append("amount", "");
        data.append("currency", "");
        // data.append("file_1", fs.createReadStream("D6Qe4Dd7b/logo256.png"));

        var config = {
            method: "post",
            url: "https://dev.llp.cpm/api/Saveticket/save",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                ...data.getHeaders(),
            },
            data: data,
        };

        axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error", error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please share nodejs code as well

Comment: what else do you want to see? this is the controller, and there is a route to call this controller.... 

app.post( "/support/ticket/create",  support_ticket_controller.add);